# Add-content command gives me "Access is Denied" UnautorizedAccessException Error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a registry key value in a bunch of remote computers. And write back the value to a shared folder in my PC. However, when I specify the output to be written to the shared folder in my PC, I get access denied error. I am running PowerShell as an admin.

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\AutoSug\Computers.txt"
$output_path = "\\mycomputername\powershell\output.csv"
$setscript = 
{
    param($output_path)
    $hostname = (Get-CIMInstance CIM_ComputerSystem).Name
    $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    if ($objExcel.Version -eq "12.0")
    {
        $HKEY_USERS = Get-ChildItem REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS | where-object { ($_.Name -like "*S-1-5-21*") -and ($_.Name -notlike "*_Classes") } 
        $Users = @()
        $value = @()
        foreach ($User in $HKEY_USERS) 
        {  
            $PROFILESID = Get-ChildItem REGISTRY::"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" | Where-Object { $_.name -like "*" + $USER.PSChildName + "*" }  
            $SID = $PROFILESID.PSChildName 
            foreach ($value in $SID)
            {
                $key = Get-Item REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\$VALUE\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preferences -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $gold = $key.property
                if($gold -like 'ShowAutoSug')
                {
                    $grail = (Get-ItemProperty REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\$VALUE\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preferences).ShowAutoSug
                    $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($value)
                    $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
                    $hostname, $objUser, $value , $grail | Add-Content $output_path
                } 
                else
                {
                    $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($value)
                    $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
                    $hostname,$objUser, $value , "The Auto Complete is not disabled" | Add-Content $output_path
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $setscript -ArgumentList $output_path
}
```

The exact error message:

> ```
> Access to the path '\\mycomputername\powershell\output.csv' is denied.
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
> ```

Comment: hmm. nope this is an error in copy paste.. there are two backslashes in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing  a "second hop" when you are trying to write the output to a shared folder, this requires that the credentials be delegated to the target computer. 
You need to enable [CredSSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.wsman.management/enable-wsmancredssp) with the command Enable-WSManCredSSP both in localhost and remote computer.
Then you must use CreddSSP in invoke-command.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock $setscript 
-ArgumentList $output_path -Authentication Credssp -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Comment: Hi. I thought about it. But the shared folder is located in my own computer. Basically there is no point "c" only point A which is my pc and point B which is the pc from which the registry values are pulled from and written back to my pc, my qualm with using credssp is its security issue. I cannot pass my credentials to other pcs. Thanks

Comment: The thing is that you're trying to access the shared folder in point b, that makes a "point c". It doesn't matter if is it your computer or another one, because you're using the UNC path and you need credentials in "point B" for that.

Answer (score 0):

When I interact with remote computer, I usually use the complete path with the c$. Don't know if it's applicable in your case. So :

```
"\\mycomputername\c$\powershell\output.csv"
```